# WinForms Application WPF Modal Dialog don't working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, dialog, modal-dialog

I have MainForm opening Forms and WPF Windows like this:

WPF Window:

```
var window = CreateWindowInstance();
var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(window) {Owner = Handle};
window.Show();
```

Form:

```
var form = CreateFormInstance();
form.Owner = this;
form.Show();
```

Then i need a WPF Window as a modal dialog calling it from a thread like this:

```
BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
{
    var window = GetWindowInstance();

    var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(window) {Owner = Handle};

    window.ShowDialog();
}));
```

But when dialog appears, you can select in the taskbar other windows, and work a few things like shorcuts (custom ones or even ALT+F4) or if is an control focused you can trigger it with key enter.

Comment: have you checked with `ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(form);`